# Doubt in distributing 20 distinct books equally among 4 students

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can you distribute 20 distinct books equally among 4 students?

The answer given to the above question in my assignment is

$${20 \choose 5}×{15 \choose 5}×{10 \choose 5}×{5 \choose 5}$$

I clearly understand that we start by first selecting 5 books out of the 20 in ${20 \choose 5}$ ways and giving it to a student, and then from the remaining 15 books we again select 5 in ${15 \choose 5}$ ways and give it to another student and so on...

My question is why aren't we multiplying the above answer with $4!$ in the end? Shouldn't we consider that the four sets of books (5 each) can be given to four students in $4!$ ways?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That has been taken into account already. For gaining some intuition: distribute 2 books equally over 2 students and see what happens.

Comment: I see where this can be confusing. Perhaps you think "well what if Alice and Bob switch places?" But there is already a combination that corresponds to that (where all five from one student are swapped with all five from another).

Comment: Giving Adam books 1-5 and then giving Barry books 6-10 etc... is the same result as giving Barry books 6-10 and then giving Adam books 1-5 etc...  In the end the books received by each student were the same.  We consider these distributions of books to be different if and only if there is at least one book which is given to a different student in the one distribution than in the other distribution.  The order in which the students lined up to receive their books is irrelevant.

Comment: In stead of the formula in your question you can also go for $\frac{20!}{5!5!5!5!}$. So $20!$ orders divided $4$ times by $5!$ in order to repair multiple counting.

Comment: Dope slap to me if anyone read a comment I left for three seconds.....  If we sort among the students we will be double counting.  Giving "War And Peace", "History of Genetics", "My Life among the Somoans" "Algebra 1", "Green Eggs and Ham" as the first group to Jane, would be the same as giving  "War And Peace", "History of Genetics", "My Life among the Somoans" "Algebra 1", "Green Eggs and Ham" as the third group to Jane.  So diving of the books takes that into account.

Comment: Here, rather than "*first selecting 5 books out of the 20 and giving it* **to a student**" this is imprecise.  What is actually happening is "*first selecting 5 books out of the 20 and giving it* **to Adam**"  (*or rather to "the first student" where "first" here is defined in some arbitrary way, e.g. having ordered the students by name, by height, age, etc... There is always some way to arbitrarily order a finite set of objects*)

Comment: Alterntively we could say There are $5$ of $20$ books to $1$ of $4$ student and $5$ of $15$ books to $1$ of $3$ students we'd get $_{20}C_5\cdot 4\times _{15}C_5\cdot 3\times_{10}C_5\cdot 2\times_{5}C_5\cdot 1=_{20}C_5\times _{15}C_5\times_{10}C_5\times_{5}C_5\cdot 4!$ but then we have to divide by $4!$ as the order of the students don't matter.

Comment: Alternatively still, we could say that there are $\binom{19}{4}\binom{14}{4}\binom{9}{4}\binom{4}{4}$ ways in which we can split the 20 books into four *unlabeled* groups of five books each, and then choose which student received which pile in $4!$ ways giving a total of $\binom{19}{4}\binom{14}{4}\binom{9}{4}\binom{4}{4}4!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to offer something worthwhile in an answer here, but my presentation may help crystallize the analysis in the OP's mind.

Let the students be named A, B, C, D.
Arbitrarily assume that A will be given books first, then B, then C, then D.

There are $\binom{20}{5}$ possible collections of 5 books to give to A.

For each collection given to A, 
there are $\binom{15}{5}$ possible collections of 5 books from those remaining books
to give to B.

For each distribution of 10 books to A and B (collectively) 
there are $\binom{10}{5}$ possible collections of 5 books from those remaining books
to give to C.

This logic explains the provided answer.

Multiplying by 4! would analogize to distinguishing which of the 4 people, A,B,C,D
will receive books 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th.  With respect to the original problem,
as **has** been already indicated in at least one of the comments:

Letting each of the 4 students have the exact same distribution of books, but **distinguishing** the distributions by the order in which the students
receive the books is inappropriate here.